# what is this code mean in python,

Tags: python

```
def a():
    print 'sss'

print getattr(a, "_decorated_function", a).__name__
```

it print :

```
a
```

thanks

**updated**

my code:

```
def a():
    w='www'

print getattr(a,'w')
```

but it print :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\zjm_code\a.py", line 8, in <module>
    print getattr(a,'w')
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'w'
```

Comment: you need to start reading docs: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr

Comment: since you're a beginner, you are not going to be using getattr() much, if at all.

Comment: Please update the title to more specifically match the question and perhaps clarify it.

What are your purpose with the question, to understand getattr or to solver your problem in the updated section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the **Updated** question

Functions must be given their attributes after declaration.

```
def a():
    pass

a.w = 'www'
print a.w
```

Another method that is more similar with other OO languages is to use a class. This example will make a static attribute:

```
class a:
    w = 'www'

print a.w
```

This will make w shared between all instances of class a, which is most useful as a constant in the program. If you on the other will be working with the variable and changing its value, it it better to do the following:

```
class b:
    def __init__(self):
        self.w = 'www'

c = b()
print c.w
```

Comment: Besides, you are completely wrong, functions do have attributes. Everything is an object in python, remember? read the first lines of http://diveintopython.org/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html .

Comment: @KillianDS sorry about that, fixed!

Comment: KillianDS, technically functions do have attributes (such as __name__), but obviously those attributes are not the local variables. I think you can get at the local variables through inspect or parser, or something, but it's not really easy.

Answer (score 4):

See the [documentation for getattr in Python](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr). The reason it is printing "a", is because "a" has no attribute named "_decorated_function", and the third parameter to getattr() is a default value to return in the event that the first parameter has no attribute with the name of the second parameter. So, your code is the same as:

```
print a.__name__
```

Not suprisingly, a's name is "a", hence you get that as the output. By the way, I strongly suggest that you search the Python documentation prior to posting questions here on StackOverflow, as you are more likely to get answers there sooner. You might also find my [Development and Coding Search](http://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/coding/resources/references/development-search) custom search engine useful in finding the relevant Python reference documentation for future queries.

Answer (score 1):

If `a` has an attribute called `_decorated_function` then it returns what that attribute contains, otherwise it returns `a`. Seriously, this is all [in the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr).

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a guess:

The code can be broken into 2 steps:

```
func = getattr(a, "_decorated_function", a)
print func.__name__
```

Ignore the first line.

The second line prints the name of `func`, which in your case happens to be `'a'`. No surprise.

The first line is there for the case of decorators:

```
class My_decorator:
    def __init__(self,func):
        self._decorated_function = func
    def __call__(self,arg):
        self._decorated_function(arg+1)

@My_decorator
def a(i):
    print i

print a(0)
>>> 1

print a._decorated_function.__name__
>>> a
```

So the objects that you will be calling `getattr(a, "_decorated_function", a)` are expected to be either functions, or classes that have "decorated" a function.